# Generic <From> Conversion in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, type-conversion

I'm implementing a function `pub fn parse_unsigned<T>(&mut self) -> Result<T, CustomError>` to convert a `Vec<u8>` to `T`. Here `T` could range from `u8` to `u64` and `self` contains a `input` field defined as `input: 'de [u8]`. Currently my method looks like this,

```rs
  pub fn parse_unsigned<T>(&mut self) -> Result<T, CustomError>
  where
    T: Sized,
  {
    let length = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
    if self.input.len() < length {
      return Err(CustomError::UnexpectedEOF);
    }
    let res = match length {
      1 => {
        let byte = self.next_byte()?;
        T::from(byte)
      }
      2 => {
        let bytes = self.next_bytes(length)?;
        T::from(u16::from_le_bytes([bytes[0], bytes[1]]))
      }
      4 => {
        let bytes = self.next_bytes(length)?;
        T::from(u32::from_le_bytes([bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]]))
      }
      8 => {
        let bytes = self.next_bytes(length)?;
        T::from(u64::from_le_bytes([
          bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], bytes[4], bytes[5], bytes[6], bytes[7],
        ]))
      }
      _ => return Err(CustomError::InvalidTypeSize),
    };
    Ok(res)
  }
```

but I get the following errors

```
 │   expected type parameter `T` 
 │          found type `u8` 
 │   mismatched types rustc (E0308) [65, 25]
 │   expected type parameter `T` 
 │          found type `u16` 
 │   mismatched types rustc (E0308) [69, 25]
 │   expected type parameter `T` 
 │          found type `u32` 
 │   mismatched types rustc (E0308) [73, 25]
 │   expected type parameter `T` 
 │          found type `u64`
```

I know I need to bound the traits but I don't know which one. I've tried doing `Sized From<u8> + From<u16> + From<u32> + From<u64>` which seems to work but then I can't call the function and it errors with

```
 │     the trait bound `u32: From<u64>` is not satisfied rustc (E0277) [136, 43]
 │      the following other types implement trait `From<T>`: 
 │        <u32 as From<bool>> 
 │        <u32 as From<char>> 
 │        <u32 as From<u8>> 
 │        <u32 as From<u16>> 
 │        <u32 as From<NonZeroU32>> 
 │        <u32 as From<Ipv4Addr>>
```

Comment: The error seems to make sense? You're asking for a u32 output, your function can parse u64s, a u64 can't be converted to a u32. Therefore you get a compilation error. You may want to look at `TryFrom`. Or reconsider the use of such a "god function". Also you don't need to specifiy that `T: Sized`, that's pretty much the one default bound.

Comment: Thank You @Masklinn! That makes sense. I used to `TryFrom` to fix it and I did a `try_into()` in the match arms. The errors seems to have gone. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Always prefer `TryInto`/`Into` over `TryFrom`/`From` in bounds, the latter gives you the former but not the other way round, so the former is more general.

Comment: I haven't played much with traits but that is genuinely helpful. Thank you @cafce25!!

Comment: You might find the [`byteorder`](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) crate useful…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with explaining why `From` isn't implemented for integers with more bits to fewer bits. When you're converting from a 64-bit integer to a 32-bit integer, you have the potential to lose information, so only `TryFrom` is implemented for those type pairings, like [`TryFrom<u64> for u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#impl-TryFrom%3Cu64%3E-for-u32). You *are* able to cast using `as` though, but `From` isn't implemented because `From` implies the conversion between the types is perfect and infallible, which `u64` to `u32` is not.

Returning different concrete types within a generic function is tricky without an underlying trait you're leveraging. One option you have is to move the `parse_unsigned<T>()` function into a trait with a generic type that you implement on `Vec<u8>`. Assuming your struct is keeping track of an index internally for calling `next_bytes()`, you'll also want to provide an index and return the number of bytes consumed from the method. It could look something like this:

```rust
trait ParseUnsigned<T> {
    // Return the number of bytes "consumed" by the parse
    fn parse_unsigned(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<(T, usize), CustomError>;
}
```

You would then implement it 4 times for each of the integer types you want to parse:

```rust
impl ParseUnsigned<u8> for Vec<u8> {
    fn parse_unsigned(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<(u8, usize), CustomError> {
        if self.len() <= idx {
            return Err(CustomError::UnexpectedEOF);
        }

        let val = u8::from(self[idx]);
        Ok((val, 1))
    }
}

impl ParseUnsigned<u16> for Vec<u8> {
    fn parse_unsigned(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<(u16, usize), CustomError> {
        if self.len() <= idx + 1 {
            return Err(CustomError::UnexpectedEOF);
        }

        let val = u16::from_le_bytes([self[idx], self[idx+1]]);
        Ok((val, 2))
    }
}

// Implementation for u32 and u64...
```

Then, in your original `parse_unsigned<T>()`, you would call the trait method and declare a `where` clause indicating `Vec<u8>` implements `ParseUnsigned` for the input `T`:

```rust
pub fn parse_unsigned<T>(&mut self) -> Result<T, CustomError>
where
    Vec<u8>: ParseUnsigned<T>,
{
    let (val, n_bytes) = self.input.parse_unsigned(self.idx)?;
    self.idx += n_bytes;

    Ok(val)
}
```

Since I'm not sure how you're updating the buffer internally, I suggested keeping track of the index since that's the method I would probably use. You could change that to whatever method you're using instead.

---

Another option you have is to split the method into separate ones for each type, but that's less ideal. Something like

```rust
pub fn parse_unsigned_u16(&mut self) -> Result<u16, CustomError>
```

It's more verbose, but it doesn't require any traits.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Crothers. Internally I'm "mutating the buffer" / "eating the bytes" from the start of the buffer such that I don't have to keep a cursor around. I did solve it similarly to your idea & @Masklinn `TryFrom` but I condensed it down to a `fn` instead. I'll post below all the 4 methods that are associated with the solution.

Comment: Rather that implementing `ParseUnsigned<T> for Vec<u8>`, I would have a non-generic `ParseUnsigned` trait and implement that for `u8`, `u16`, … Then you can call it simply with `u32::parse_unsigned (&v)`.

Comment: @Jmb Wouldn't that result in the same issue the OP had with returning concrete types in a generic function? It seems to me that writing a non-generic `ParseUnsigned` trait as you describe would act exactly the same as the existing `from_le_bytes()` function, which the OP was struggling to use on its own because it returns a concrete type. Using a generic trait allows the `parse_unsigned()` call to return `T`, which avoids the issue.

Comment: A non generic `parse_unsigned` in a trait can return `Self` (or `Result<Self, CustomError>`).

Comment: Yes of course, but if all you do is use, for example, `u32::parse_unsigned()` and define the top-level `T` as `T: ParseUnsigned`, you'll get the error `expected type parameter T, found u32`. You still have to convert it to `T` because `parse_unsigned()` returns a concrete type, not a generic. My method returns a generic type, so it works as-is.

Comment: What I'm suggesting works exactly like your method. The only difference is that instead of `self.input.parse_unsigned (self.idx)`, you would write `T::parse_unsigned (&self.input[self.idx..])`, which returns a `T` just like your generic method.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, my mistake. Sorry for my confusion. I like your method better.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to @Nicholas Crothers and @Masklinn.

I solved it with the help of `TryFrom` trait. Here is the updated code with four methods, `peek_byte`, `next_byte`, `next_bytes` and `parse_unsigned`.

```rs
/// Returns the next byte in the input without consuming it.
pub fn peek_byte(&self) -> Result<u8, CustomError> {
    self.input.first().map(|&v| v).ok_or(CustomError::EOF)
}

/// Consumes the next byte in the input.
pub fn next_byte(&mut self) -> Result<u8, CustomError> {
    let byte = self.peek_byte()?;
    self.input = &self.input[1..];
    Ok(byte)
}

/// Consumes the next `length` bytes in the input.
pub fn next_bytes(&mut self, length: usize) -> Result<&'de [u8], CustomError> {
    if self.input.len() < length {
        return Err(CustomError::UnexpectedEOF);
    }
    let bytes = &self.input[..length];
    self.input = &self.input[length..];
    Ok(bytes)
}

/// Parses an unsigned integer value from the input.
pub fn parse_unsigned<T>(&mut self) -> Result<T, CustomError>
where
    T: TryFrom<u8> + TryFrom<u16> + TryFrom<u32> + TryFrom<u64>,
{
    let length = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
    if self.input.len() < length {
        return Err(CustomError::UnexpectedEOF);
    }
    match length {
        1 => {
            let byte = self.next_byte()?;
            u8::from_le_bytes([byte])
                .try_into()
                .map_err(|_| CustomError::ConversionError)
        }
        2 => {
            let bytes = self.next_bytes(length)?;
            u16::from_le_bytes([bytes[0], bytes[1]])
                .try_into()
                .map_err(|_| CustomError::ConversionError)
        }
        4 => {
            let bytes = self.next_bytes(length)?;
            u32::from_le_bytes([bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]])
                .try_into()
                .map_err(|_| CustomError::ConversionError)
        }
        8 => {
            let bytes = self.next_bytes(length)?;
            u64::from_le_bytes([
                bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], bytes[4], bytes[5], bytes[6], bytes[7],
            ])
            .try_into()
            .map_err(|_| CustomError::ConversionError)
        }
        _ => return Err(CustomError::InvalidTypeSize),
    }
}
```

The `CustomDeserializer` struct,

```rs
pub struct CustomDeserializer<'de> {
    input: &'de [u8],
}
```